# Proof that a $\sigma$-field contains the sets $A \cap B$, $A \setminus B$, and $A \triangle B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to get feedback on my proof. If it is not correct, I would appreciate it if you could only provide hints and not the full answer.

Proof that $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$.

$A,B \in \mathcal{F} \iff A^c, B^c \in \mathcal{F} \iff (A^c \cup B^c) \in \mathcal{F} \iff (A \cap B)^c \in \mathcal{F} \iff A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}.$

In the above proof, I am using De Morgan's Law to get the penultimate iff and the definition of a sigma-field for the final iff.

Proof that $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{F}$.

By definiton of a sigma-field, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$. Therefore, $A \cap B = \emptyset \iff A \setminus B.$

Proof that $A \triangle B$.

Stuck on this bit.

Comment: The second is not right. Use $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$. For $A\triangle B$, I would use the fact that it is $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.

Comment: Is this correct for the second proof: $x \in (A \setminus B) \iff (x \in A \land x \notin B) \iff (x \notin A \lor x \in B) \iff x \in (A^c \cup B) \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: You left out a complement. The second iff is wrong. You want something like $(A^c \cup B)^c$.

Comment: Revised proof: $x \in (A \setminus B) \iff (x \in A \land x \notin B) \iff (x \notin A \lor x \in B)^c \iff x \in (A^c \cup B)^c \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Yes, that works fine.

Comment: For the third proof, I'm stuck at this point and cannot infer any further and prove the symmetric difference exists in the sigma-field:$x \in A \triangle B \iff x \in [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)] \iff x \in [(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)] \iff x \in (A \setminus B) \cup x \in (B \setminus A) \iff (x \in A \land x \notin B) \cup (x \in B \land x \notin A) \iff (x \in A \land x \in B^c) \cup (x \in B \land x \in A^c) \iff x \in (A \cap B^c) \cup x \in (B \cap A^c) \iff x \in [(A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)]$.

Comment: Use the expresion for $A\cap B^c$ that you already obtained. So replace $A\cap B^c$ by $(A^c\cup B)^c$. Do something similar with the other one.

Comment: $x \in A \triangle B \iff x \in [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)] \iff x \in [(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)] \iff x \in (A \setminus B) \cup x \in (B \setminus A) \iff (x \in A \land x \notin B) \cup (x \in B \land x \notin A) \iff (x \in A \land x \in B^c) \cup (x \in B \land x \in A^c) \iff x \in (A \cap B^c) \cup x \in (B \cap A^c) \iff x \in [(A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)] \iff x \in [(A^c \cup B)^c \cup (B^c \cup A)^c)] \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Yes, it is right, but you are writing far too much. You have already proved that $A\setminus B$ is in our $\sigma$-field. By the same argument, so is $B\setminus A$. So their union $A\operatorname{\Delta} B$ is in the $\sigma$-field.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @AndréNicolas for that insight and all your help. It was actually my next question: whether I could write these proofs in a more concise way. I would really appreciate it if you could give me your proof for the $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{F}$ so that I can compare with mine, in order to improve the conciseness in my reasoning.

Comment: Depends on how much detail they want. As soon as you have explained that $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$ (if this needs explanation) you can say that $A$ and $B^c$ are in the $\sigma$-field, so by the first result you proved, so is $A\cap B^c$. Recycling is a virtue!

Comment: wow again! Hopefully I will 'see the wood for the trees' one day :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** recall that $A\triangle B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.